# Is there a way to force remove an SCCM 2007 Site Server?

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm

One of our secondary site servers in SCCM 2007 has become corrupt.  IIS, WSUS and WDS have failed.  Unfortunately, in Server 2008 there is no way to repair these server roles.  I have cleared the roles from SCCM and all but one role has cleared. I am getting an error that it cannot remove the PXE service point.  As such, the component server role will not clear and I am unable to delete the site server from the site.

Due to the corrupt state of the server, I cannot bring WDS online, and SCCM will not deinstall the PXE service point until it can talk with WDS.

Is there a good way to force remove a site server?  I need to do this before I can scrape the server and rebuild it.

Comment: To clarify, the PXE service point role is no longer listed on the site system, but in the status message viewer, the SMS_PXE_SERVICE_POINT errors each hour with the message: "SMS Site Componenet Manager failed to deinstall this component from this site system." I suspect that this is blocking full removal of the site system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Hierarchy Maintenance Tool Preinst.exe found in the `<install_directory>\bin\i386\<language code>` (See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693624.aspx) which can be used to remove secondary site objects when the `/deljob` and `/delsite` switches are used. This command can also be used to remove primary sites from a central site however you should log a call with Microsoft if you get in that far.

If you are going to rebuilt this server then you should disable all SCCM services before continuing.

Preinst.exe would be used by issuing both of these commands sequentially:

```
preinst.exe /deljob <child_site_code>

preinst.exe /delsite <child_site_code> <parent_site_code>
```

If the site does not disappear from the SCCM console after about 30 mins to an hour (it may take longer if you have a busy SCCM site hierarchy) then you can use the following queries against the parent primary SCCM site database to clean up the entries.

**Make sure you do a full backup of you primary and central sites.**

```
DELETE FROM SysResList WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM SiteBoundaryADSite WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM SiteBoundaryIPSubnet WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM SiteControl WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM SiteControlNotification WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM Sites WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM Sites_DATA WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX'
DELETE FROM SiteWork WHERE SiteCode = 'XXX' 
DELETE FROM PkgServers WHERE sitecode = 'XXX' 
DELETE FROM PkgStatus WHERE sitecode = 'XXX'
```

**Microsoft does not support or recommend altering the SCCM database outside of the functions in the SCCM console.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never seen this tool before (and I thought I was pretty good at rummaging around Technet)!  Thanks for the spot-on response!